# Glossary not being updated, document complaining about non-defined acronym

Tags: glossaries

so I am about to finish my thesis using a template the chair provided.

Yes of course I tried searching the net for solutions that fit this problem, but what I found was usually with regard to 
Up to some point all was working good, but now new acronyms are not being printed into the glossary.

I had the problem once and fixed it somhehow, but don't recall how I did so unfortunately.

The behaviour is like this:
*New acronyms are not being transferred into the glossaries
*The main document gives me a "package glossaries warning: glossary entry 'hdr' has not been defined on line %blah%.

Yeah that's right, because 'hdr' is nowhere used in the document, so I do not include it in the glossary. If I do add the 'hdr' \newacronym{}, it even shows in the glossaries with an entry on page 48. On this page there is a figure but no hdr \gls{} command.

To me it looks like the system is somehow referencing an older, already compiled version stored somewhere.

How can I get the system to force it to compile new?

I am using sharelatex.com and am quite happy with it due to the lack of needed configuration and ability to work from anywhere.

The main.tex looks like this:

```
\piivsubject{Master Thesis}
% The title of your work.
\piivtitle{My Thesis}
% Your name.
\piivauthor{The Author}
% Name of your supervisor.
\piivsupervisor{Name of Supervisor}
% The date you submit your thesis. You can substitute the command with any date.
\date{\today}

% If you want to use the glossary make sure your 'makeindex' toolchain is working correctly.
% Alternetively, you might want to look into the 'xindy' option of the glossaries package.
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\input{src/glossary}

% Abstract is optional. If you do not use an abstract, remove it.
% ---------------------------------
% Begin of abstract
\abstractchap
% \blindtext creates a paragraph of non-sense text. Replace it with your actual content.
\blindtext
% End of abstract
% ---------------------------------

% ---------------------------------
% Begin of listings
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false} % disables protrusion locally in the document
\tableofcontents
% If you should not have any figures, tables or acronyms in your paper remove the according list.
\listoffigures
\listoftables
% Uncomment the next line if you use listings in your document.
% \lstlistoflistings
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true} % enables protrusion

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
% End of listings
% ---------------------------------

% ---------------------------------
% Begin of main part
\mainmatter

\include{src/chapter_1}

\include{src/chapter_2}

% Include more chapters here.

% End of main part
% ---------------------------------

% ---------------------------------
% Begin of appendix
\appendix
% Appendix chapters are optional. Use it if you have very long tables or additional figures that
% do not belong to the main text.
% \input{src/appendix}

% Remove this from the final document
\include{src/checklist}

\backmatter

\bibliography{library}

% Fix for long URLs in bibliography
\sloppy
\printglossary
\fussy

\include{src/erklaerung}

% Consult your supervisor about the following declaration of assignment.
%\include{src/abtretungserklaerung}

% End of appendix
% ---------------------------------

\end{document}
```

I have no errors and no warnings, just some over- and underfull boxes, but the document looks how I want it to look.

What I find really weird is the reference of 'hdr' to page 48.....

Questions:
 * can this in any way be connected?
 * if it would work I could just as easily have the \newacronym{} commands in the main file instead of a separate glossary.tex file. I tried it once but didn't change anything.

Thanks a lot, any input is appreciated!

James

Comment: I see you found a solution yourself. That's great, but as the site is a Q&A please post it as an answer rather than an edit to the question.

Comment: you expect me to re-write that because you edit-deleted it? Naw, sorry. I would have copied and re-posted it, sure. Weird practice to delete valuable information imho

Comment: I've copied the text into a CW answer: this looses the fact it's your solution. As a Q&A site it's important for future visitors that the questions and answers are separate, hence the request to move the info. (Nothing ever gets deleted in that sense: the revisions are all available and there was nothing to actually re-type.)

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you have `\input{src/glossary}` just after `\begin{document}` instead of before. If you'd used `\loadglsentries` instead of `\input` it would've triggered the preamble-only message.

Comment: @JosephWright this was not meant as being rude or offensive, sry if it came across that way. Thx for the info with the history.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Changing the ordering did not change anything. Weirdest thing: The solution I posted did work this morning but does not now any more. This is really so weird....

Comment: Do you have a file with the extension `.glsdefs`? If you do, delete it and retry with `\input{src/glossary}` before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer posted by OP as an edit:

---

ehe, not long after posting this I fixed it myself.

What I did was the following: moved the glossary.tex file into the images folder and then compiled. This led to an error with no PDF created at all. Then I put back the glossary.tex file into the root of \src and pressed compile again.

To my suprise and joy it worked - working glossary again.